HoloLens2 space mapping and map reconstruction
How can Hololens2 use custom Slam data in its own application, or maximize the efficiency and performance of large space recognition? (The initial idea was to load a fixed map into the device after opening my application to help him quickly reconstruct the current environment data)
At present, I haven't found any related articles. I want to open my own application and then the Hololens2 device can use my own Slam data or map data.
